# How to display layout based on condition?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `element` called `viewtype`  like 1,2,3... from JSON file. I am getting different data based on `viewtype`.  Now in `onCreate` I need to display layout based on `viewtype`. How can I do that? based on `ifCondition`, is it possible to do that.

Answer (score 1):

At the creation of your activity or fragment, just make a condition on your viewtype, and inflate the layout you desire.

This example will be a lot more explanatory :

In an activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    switch(viewType){
        case 1:
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_2);
            break;
        default:
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_default);
            break;
    }
}
```

And in a fragment :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view;
    switch(viewType){
    case 1:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_1, container, false);
        break;
    case 2:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_2, container, false);
        break;
    default:
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_default, container, false);
        break;
    }
    return view;
}
```

But you will need to handle the different views (if there are) for each different layout so I would recommend to put methods inside each condition in order to inflate the layout and handle the different views.

Regards,
Matthieu